# Objects transformations wrong when importing from 3ds

Tags: transforms, import

When I import my tank file from 3ds format it appears in blender a little bit messed up like this:

[image]

I selected all messed up tanktracks and did *Origin to geometry*.
Then they became almost correct, but not quite:
[image]

The tank tracks in front of the tank remained incorrectly rotated.

They should look like this (this is how the tank appears in autocad)

[image]

Why does this happen? Can anyone help me?
My tank is [here (35MB)](http://files.mail.ru/E75542D098C145D5BD458214309A55CA)

I have blender 2.67.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select them all (they are selected by default after importing), press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to clear all the transformations.(Or go to the header menu > **Object** > **Clear** to find these operators.)

[image]

**P.S.:** If the result still problematic, try toggling off the **Apply Transform** in the left-hand panel in the Import window.

[image]

---

By doing so, The origins of all objects will go to one point. If you want move each origin to their individual geometry, just keep them selected, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, choose **Origin to Geometry** or **Origin to Center of Mass** to move them back to each individual objects.

Comment: thanks, but this isn't working for me. i imported a .3ds and the object look like the right scale and location but just exploded out, so i tried alt-g and i tried the import toggle but nothing puts humpty dumpty back together again. any ideas? this is the model http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/signal-lamp-3ds-free/138519

Comment: I tried that model, and it works for me here. are you sure you have tried alt g / r / s?

Comment: yes, i tried every combination, interesting, thanks, i'll try again