# From *3ds-file Imported objects have no extensiveness and are all locaed in the origin

Tags: import

Dear StackExchange Community,
I am currently trying to import a 3ds file into blender. The Problem is, that all the objects get imported into the origin of the coordinate system and have no extensiveness whatsoever.

The file I am trying to import is a 3D Model of parts of the city of Berlin, which is available for free.
http://www.businesslocationcenter.de/berlin3d-downloadportal/

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what could solve my problem?

Cheers Luke

Comment: Welcome LHC :)  3ds is a deprecated file format.  First, please check if this answers help to solve your issue: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5405/objects-transformations-wrong-when-importing-from-3ds, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24481/how-to-properly-export-scene-to-3ds-max, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14808/how-to-import-a-max-model-into-blender. Anyway, enjoy blender.se!

Comment: Could you post a link to your downloaded 3ds file please? The download site from your link is a bit awkward.

Comment: what is *extensiveness*?

Comment: I Tried the proposed threads and none of them contained a solution to my problem.

@ronald8 Here you can find the 3ds file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iu35em4s1cdtphy/FME_502A2C70_1438272925398_2307.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is a problem with scale and geometry to origin offset and so its easy to fix:

Start with a new blender scene <kbd>ctrl + N</kbd> and move the camera, cube and pointlight to another layer. In your scene properties you could set units to *metric* if you want.
In your 3D View go to top ortho view with <kbd>numpad 7+5</kbd> and toggle on the 3D view properties panel with <kbd>N</kbd>.

Import the first of your .3ds files and set "Size Constraint" to 1000 (maximum) in the import options (down left).
After import just hit <kbd>home</kbd> (View > View All) and you should see your objects. Problem is they are very far away from the center and you are not able to view both the center *and* your objects at the same time with the default viewport clipping values.

In fact your objects are ***several million*** blender units away from the center while their origins are at the center. This is a bit impractical to work with ...

To fix this I would do this:

After importing all .3ds files as described above just hit <kbd>home</kbd> to bring them all to view. Place the 3d cursor where you want to have your new coordinate center. Select all objects and set their origins to the 3d cursor. Next <kbd>shift + C</kbd> to center cursor and <kbd>shift + S</kbd> >*Selection to Cursor*. Finally <kbd>home</kbd> again and all should be fine.

[image]